# How to use LED holder when mounting on a case with PCB inside?

Tags: led, pcb, soldering, mounting-holes

I am making a case with a front and back piece with the PCB mounted on the back piece with LED supposed to be mounted in the holder in the front case piece.

I was planning on soldering the LED to the PCB holes first then trying to squeeze it into the bezel holder while fitting the front case to the back case piece. However that will damage the straight LED leads and damage the LED when I remove the front case in the future as the bezel holders either snap in or screw in.

[image]

How are widely sold 5 mm LED holders meant to be used and what is the normal way to do what I am trying to achieve?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

You  could just drill a hole in the panel the right size to pass the LED, and mount the LED the right distance above the board.  No need for any LED holders.

Answer (score 1):

These holders are intended for panel-mounting of LEDs and wiring them to PCBs with sufficient slack.

[image]